# Gnuplot trying to plot data from file "warning: Skipping data file with no valid points, x range is invalid"

Tags: file, plot, gnuplot

Hi I'm trying to plot data from a file in gnuplot but I keep getting the error message

```
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points ^ x range is invalid
```

The data file is

```
1   1

2   2

3   3

4   4
```

I am using a windows laptop so I first run gnuplot.exe. Then I change the directory (`cd '...'`) to the one containing the data file. Then I use the command `plot 'tmpfile' using 1:2 with lines`. Does anyone know why this is not working for me?

(If I copy the data to a .gnu file I can plot it, but I want to skip that step if I can)

Comment: Is it possible that your `tmpfile` was created by a tool that adds some non-printable character at the start of the line? For instance some Windows editors save each file with an initial <BOM> record that gnuplot does not like.

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I check and change this?

Comment: @cppplanet how do you create your data file? With some text editor, e.g. Notepad, etc? What does WindowsExplorer show for the file type?

Comment: @theozh I've saved it as a .dat file. When I use the command "plot 'tmpfile.dat' using 1:2 with lines" I still get the same error though

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I resolved the issue by opening the data file with notepad, clicking save as, then changing the encoding to UTF-8